# Assigning Dynamic Columns via SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to map columns according to the number of months ahead of a subtraction between two dates.

Example: `2012-10-01` - `2010-10-01` = 24

I need to allocate 24 columns (to insert into a temporary table), with the names of all the months between `01.10.2012` and `01.10.2010` => October, November,..... October.

Each column represents a month like this:

October November December January February March April May June July August September October November December January February March April May June July August September October

**table_Temporal**

```
City    
Area    
Production => Oct,Nov,Dec...etc...
Yield
```

ok, I have a figure called "production" of which I show the distribution by month, according to a time called "the month of harvest."

example:

Production => harvest date
100 => '2010 / 10/02 '
200 => '2011 / 11/01 '
100 => '2012 / 10/10 '

The result set would be

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds doable but scary can you give more information like waht you are trying to do.  We can get away with inserting into a common temp table and then pivoting based on a month or date.

Comment: ok, I have a figure called "production" of which I show the distribution by month, according to a time called "the month of harvest."

example:

Production => harvest date
100 => '2010 / 10/02 '
200 => '2011 / 11/01 '
100 => '2012 / 10/10 '

The result set would be

  "Production" => 2010-10 => = 2011-11> 2012-10
                    400 => 100 => 200 => 100

Comment: I don't believe you can have column names that are the same.  Each needs to be unique.  So, you would have to have some other value to ensure you have a unique column name.  OR you could have Jan - Dec and a Year column, so you'd have 13 total columns, and one row per year (if that fits your model).

Comment: column name is not important, I assign different names, I need is how to allocate the number of columns as the number of months

Comment: The simple answer here is not to create dynamic columns at all.  Its a fairly simple straightforward solution.  you have 2 fields, one a date field and the other the number of harvests.  For instance in your case October with 100.  The date field is pivoted based on MONTH-YEAR combination.  Your actual table contains entries for days in october, november, december, etc.  What makes them unique is the month year combination and pivot those values with a sum of harvest / production.  Do you want this solution?

Comment: Yes the idea is take the production based on the month and year

Comment: I will try my best to whip you up a solution tomorrow.  Sorry I have had no time today, am working on my taxes :).

Comment: @ale - I posted a solution below - good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need a single table without any use of cursors or dynamic creation of columns.  The solution is to pivot the results to get the final output

```
2010-10  2010-11 2010-12 2011-1...
  50      100     25       70
```

That is the combination of year and month is what makes the column unique and the sum is done for the entire month and placed in the correct column.  One issue that arose quickly is when using `PIVOT` you need to list out your column names.  For instance `... PIVOT (SUM(Harvest)) FOR ([2011-10], [2011-11]...` but we can avoid this all together with the use of `STUFF` and `XML Path`.

Here is what you can do, I used TEMP tables, but you can change this to reference your real tables.  First the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
 (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TheDate datetime,
    Harvest int
 )
```

Then insert some dummy data:

```
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('10/11/2011', 50)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('10/11/2012', 100)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('10/1/2011', 20)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('12/11/2011', 50)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('11/11/2011', 50)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('11/12/2011', 150)
```

Display the results:

```
SELECT * FROM #Test
```

Result is:

```
ID   TheDate                 Harvest
1   2011-10-11 00:00:00.000 50
2   2012-10-11 00:00:00.000 100
3   2011-10-01 00:00:00.000 20
4   2011-12-11 00:00:00.000 50
5   2011-11-11 00:00:00.000 50
6   2011-11-12 00:00:00.000 150
```

Here is where the magic happens:

```
DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @listCol = STUFF((  
                          SELECT DISTINCT
                          ],[' + ltrim(str(YEAR(TheDate))) + 
                          '-' + CAST (MONTH(TheDate) as varchar(50))
                          FROM    
                   #Test
                  ORDER BY 
                '],[' + ltrim(str(YEAR(TheDate))) + '-' + 
                            CAST(MONTH(TheDate) as varchar(50))
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                                    ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
SET @query = 
'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT 
             ltrim(str(YEAR(TheDate))) + 
             ''-'' + CAST (MONTH(TheDate) as varchar(50)) AS TheCol, 
             Harvest
            FROM 
             #Test
            ) src
        PIVOT (SUM(Harvest) FOR TheCol
        IN ('+@listCol+')) AS pvt'
```

Then execute this query:

`EXECUTE (@query)`

The result:

```
2011-10    2011-11     2011-12    2012-10
70          200         50    100
```

And don't forget to get rid of the temp table

`DROP TABLE #Test`

Remember I am using my test data, so you can add to it as you like.  Here is a graphical output of everything:

[image]